# How to animate on each state change using framer motion

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I thought on ever render framer motion would re-do my animation because the inital is set to hide and the animate is set to show. But this is not the case.

How can I get this to re-play the animation on each state change ?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { motion} from "framer-motion";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Screen = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setState(Math.random());
    }, 4000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Title variants={variants} animate="show" initial="hide">
      {console.log("re-render")}
      {`screen ${state}`}
    </Title>
  );
};

const Title = styled(motion.div)`
  color: red;
`;

export const variants = {
  show: {
    opacity: 1,
    y: 0,
    transition: {
      ease: "easeOut",
      duration: 0.3
    }
  },
  hide: {
    y: -20,
    opacity: 0
  }
};

export default Screen;
```

Answer (score 22):

If you just want to remount element use a `key` prop on it, like that:

```
  return (
    <motion.div key={state} variants={variants} animate={'show'} initial="hide">
      {`screen ${state}`}
    </motion.div>
  );
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-69051279-76yit) (please provide Codesandbox with reproduction in the future)

It looks weird but it works if that is the effect that you want.

For smoother animation I would use animation controls or `AnimatePresence` probably.

Comment: That's what I'm doing about firing off a state change.

Comment: What if we want to animate not just when it shows but also when it changes? Right now it changes instantly and is not smooth

Comment: Such an elegant solution.  I've spent some hours earlier on today trying to calculate if something had changed, and it's all just in the key.

Answer (score 3):

You can change animation on state as well.

Something like this:

```
export const SingleListView = () => {
  const [animation, setAnimation] = useState(false);

  const variants = {
    show: {
      opacity: 1,
      y: 0,
      transition: {
        ease: 'easeOut',
        duration: 0.3,
      },
    },
    hide: {
      y: -20,
      opacity: 0,
    },
  };

  return (
    <>
      <motion.div key="animation-on-state" variants={variants} animate={animation ? 'hide' : 'show'}>
        <div>{`${animation}`}</div>
      </motion.div>
      <button onClick={() => setAnimation((state) => !state)}>
        BUTTON {`${animation}`}
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```