# Is there a way to add animation transitions when an element changes state in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, animation, react-hooks, next.js

In my project, I want to make a nav-bar/header and search bar just like the one on Apple's desktop website. The way it should work is that initially, the search bar should be hidden while the header is visible. When I click a button on the header, it should trigger a state hook that that makes the search bar visible while hiding the header at the same time. When this happens, there needs to be a smooth transition between states where, the header links fade out and get smaller and reveal the search bar.

I was able to figure out how to get the header to make the search bar visible and hide itself, but I can't figure out how to make smooth transitions work that activate during a change in state.

Here's my Code:

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    XMarkIcon
} from '@heroicons/react/24/solid'
import {
    useState,
    useEffect
} from 'react';
type Props = {}
const SearchBar = (props: Props) => {
    const [show, setShow, ] = useState((false));
    return (<div className="bg-gray-800">
 {show? <p></p>:true}
 {show? <p></p>:false}
 
 
<div className={show? "hidden" : " h-8 z-20 fixed left-0 top-0 right-0 transition-all duration-500 ease p-10"} id="nav-container">

{/* <button>onClick={()=> setShow(false)}</button> */}


        <nav className= "w-[1000px]  ml-auto mr-auto pl-2 pr-2 transition-transform duration-400 ease">
   
            <ul className="flex justify-between content-center"  id="desktop-nav">
              
                <li>
                    <a href="#" id="link-logo"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
          
                    <a className="text-[#fff] text-sm opacity-50 hover:opacity-100"  href="#">Mac</a>
                  
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a  className="text-[#fff] text-sm opacity-50 hover:opacity-100" href="#">iPad</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a className="text-[#fff] text-sm opacity-50 hover:opacity-100" href="#">iPhone</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a className="active:transition-all duration-800 text-[#fff] text-sm opacity-50 hover:opacity-100" href="#">Watch</a>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                    <a className="active:transition-all duration-800 text-[#fff] text-sm opacity-50 hover:opacity-100" href="#">TV</a>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                    <a className="text-[#fff] text-sm opacity-50  hover:opacity-100" href="#">Music</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a  onClick={()=> setShow(true)} className=" text-[#fff] text-sm opacity-50 hover:opacity-100  transition-all duration-500 " href="#">Support</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a className="text-[#fff] text-sm opacity-50 hover:opacity-100" href="#" id="link-search"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a className="text-[#fff] text-sm opacity-50 hover:opacity-100 " href="#" id="link-bag"></a>
                </li>
              <li>
               
              </li>
            </ul>
           
        </nav>
        
</div>




{/* Search Bar Section*/}
{show?
   <div id="search-container" className="  w-[60%] mt-0 mb-0 mr-auto ml-auto
    fixed top-0 z-20 pr-11 pl-11 left-0 right-0 ">

    <div id="link-search" className="absolute left-3 ">
    <div id="search-bar">
    <form action="" className="mt-0 mb-0 ml-auto mr-auto m w-full">

    <input className="w-full h-11 m-auto outline-none border-none bg-transparent text-white font-sans
      text-xl "type="text" placeholder="Search apple.com/ca"></input>


    </form>
    </div>
    {/* Styling for Close/X button*/}

    <XMarkIcon onClick={()=> setShow(false)} id="link-close"className="absolute top-2.5  left-[580px]  opacity-40 h-5 w-5 text-blue-500 transition-all duration-500
    hover:opacity-100 block bg-center bg-no-repeat cursor-pointer"/>

<div className="bg-white text-black absolute left-0 right-0 pt-4 pb-4 pl-2 pr-2 rounded-b-lg w-[600px]" id="quick-links">
<h2 className="text-lg font-bold ml-8 mr-8 mt-2.5">Quick Links</h2>
<ul className="mt-3">

<li>
                        <a className="inline-block w-full pt-2 pb-2 pl-14 pr-14 hover:bg-[#f5f5f5] hover:text-[#2997ff]" href="#">Visiting an Apple Store FAQ</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a className="inline-block w-full pt-2 pb-2 pl-14 pr-14 hover:bg-[#f5f5f5] hover:text-[#2997ff]" href="#">Shop Apple Store Online</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a className="inline-block w-full pt-2 pb-2 pl-14 pr-14 hover:bg-[#f5f5f5] hover:text-[#2997ff]" href="#">Accessories</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a className="inline-block w-full pt-2 pb-2 pl-14 pr-14 hover:bg-[#f5f5f5] hover:text-[#2997ff]" href="#">AirPods</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a className="inline-block w-full pt-2 pb-2 pl-14 pr-14 hover:bg-[#f5f5f5] hover:text-[#2997ff]" href="#">AirTag</a>
                    </li>
</ul>

</div>
    
    </div>

    </div>
    :true}

{show?
     <div className="fixed  w-full h-screen left-0 top-0 " id="overlay show"> </div>
     :true}
      {/* Overlay Background: bg-[#606060]*/}
      
 

    </div>)
}
export default SearchBar
```

I'm using React and Typescript in Next.js for this Project. I'm also using Tailwindcss

Answer (score 0):

I think [Framer](https://www.framer.com/) might be what you're looking for. It's a library that enables the animations of React components on a page and while the component is entering and also leaving. Check out this [snadbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-69051279-76yit) as an example (It's not mine, it was published [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69051279/how-to-animate-on-each-state-change-using-framer-motion#:%7E:text=If%20you%20just%20want%20to%20remount%20element%20use%20a%20key%20prop%20on%20it%2C%20like%20that%3A), by @Danila